# DirectoryNotFoundException when running Blazor application with Blazorise

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, blazorise

I did a full setup by official docs https://blazorise.com/docs/start. Next I try to use **RichTextEdit** component for instance. [image] There is some problem. [image]

Are there any specific customization for **Blazorise**? Where can I find additional info?

Comment: https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/richtextedit

Comment: Thanks, but I did it. Looks like I have incorrect Blazorise setup. It cannot find _content directory.